# Fw tools using error

Tags: geojson, json, tab, fwtools

I am using Fw tools. And I am writting cmd screen:

```
ogr2ogr -f \"GeoJSON\" -t_srs WGS84  D:\\electric_Data1\\direk.json  D:\\electric_Data1\\ag_direk.TAB
```

tried.

And I have a error.

error code:

```
unable to find driver '"GeoJSON"' 
The following drivers are avaible: 

esri shape file
mapinfo file
bla bla bla
GeoJSON
bla bla bla
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do not use FWTools anymore. It is outdated for some time now.

Running Windows, you can get the latest GDAL binaries at http://gisinternals.com/sdk

In the command line, you don't have to write \"GEOJSON\". -f GeoJSON should run fine.

Comment: I am succeed. I didnt use "\" operators. just like:  
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" -t_srs WGS84  D:\electric_Data1\direk.json  D:\electric_Data1\ag_direk.TAB